# chrome slows only in datalist and not in span

Tags: ajax

i have ajax / jsp project. i am bringing a itemcode from the table to a datalist field and also in a span tag display, using like %blah%. however it is limited to 15 records at a time.

The question is , the data comes much faster in span tag while in the datalist, it is coming about 5 seconds slower.

Ironically, it is working faster in some other slower PC, [32 bit, 2 GB , windows 7] while it is slower in a faster PC [64 bit, 4 GB, windows 8].

I am puzzled. same code.. same data... slower in faster PC and faster in slower PC. especially in datalist only. not in span. in span tag, it comes i fraction of sec.

Comment: Don’t think you can “compare” datalist and a span in that regard. For the datalist, the browser provides search functionality, filtering it automatically by the typed input. Your span presumably has no such functionality implemented, so you are comparing apples and oranges here to begin with.

Comment: i understand that. I mentioned span so that we can presume there is no network delay nor DB related performance issue nor any query fine tuning issue. just to segregate this issue to browser level, i mentioned that